# TextureView crashes when trying to getHardwareLayer

Tags: android

This seems to happen to a lot of devices for app in production on 4.2.x but I can't reproduce it on my own devices, (4.1, and 4.0 are not affected). Looking at the source code for TextureView it looks like mAttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer.createHardwareLayer(mOpaque) returned null and NPE was triggered because of that. I was thinking if this only happens on devices that does not support hardware acceleration, but it looks like it happens a lot Nexus 4 devices are affected as well (not my own Nexus 4). 'android:hardwareAccelerated="true"' is also in the manifest.

[TextureView.java line 379](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/TextureView.java#L379) android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer

Fatal Exception java.lang.NullPointerException

TextureView.java line 379

android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer

View.java line 13087

android.view.View.getDisplayList

View.java line 13162

android.view.View.getDisplayList

View.java line 13896

android.view.View.draw

ViewGroup.java line 3024

android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild

ViewGroup.java line 2893

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the view was removed onSurfaceCreated, you cannot remove the view anymore in 4.2 and should not do it at all. (as per romain: "You are doing something bad!")